# Trouble in enquing all js files under certain directory

Tags: theme-development, jquery

I am using _s theme .I have all js files under js folder.My code

```
function _s_scripts() {
$js_dir = get_template_directory_uri() . "/js/";
foreach(glob($js_dir.'/*.*') as $file) {
$label = str_replace(".", "", $file);
wp_enqueue_script($label, $js_dir . $file . '.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0');
}
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', '_s_scripts' );
```

Upon inspecting I found no jquery files loaded.PS I want to use glob function.

Comment: Any progress on that question? Please do follow up on answers to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

i think you're putting too many extra bits on the file and path strings.

try this :

```
function _s_scripts() {
$js_dir = get_template_directory_uri() . "/js/";
foreach(glob($js_dir.'*.*') as $file) {
$label = str_replace(".", "", $file);
wp_enqueue_script($label, $file , array('jquery'), '1.0.0');
}
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', '_s_scripts' );
```

when I run a similar function locally against a dir, the extra "/" and extra ".js" you were adding can causing files to not be found. Also - you added the `$js_dir` a second time, when `$file` will already have that information associated to it

edit:

to better explain : `$file` already had ".js" in its name, when you appended a second ".js" - those files logically do not exist (unless you have naming conventions that were not mentioned.

Also - in `$js_dir` - you already have the trailing forward slash, but when you try to search for `/*.*`  - thats not a valid pattern so it further confuses glob.

this is at least how I understand it. A test harness I wrote was :

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
$js_dir = "/Users/MYUSER/Sites/";
$fileglob = glob($js_dir.'*.*');
echo count($fileglob);
foreach( $fileglob as $file) {
    $label = str_replace(".", "", $file);
    echo $file; 
    }
    echo "done";
?>
```

One more Edit:

To make this a better search, instead of `*.*` do this : 
....

```
foreach(glob($js_dir.'*.js') as $file) {
```

that way, if you have other, system files (like thumbnail icons, text files, etc.. ) they don't get gathered up with the glob

Comment: and for reference - this is general php and not a wordpress specific issue. made some edits to the answer to be more complete.

Answer (score 0):

Ancient thread.

Helpful above, but `get_template_directory_uri()` won't work because glob needs a path name, not a URI (url).

We need `get_template_directory()`.

```
$js_files = get_template_directory() . '/ng/';
foreach(glob($js_files.'*.js') as $file) {
  $labelarray = explode("/", $file);
  $label = str_replace(".", "", substr(array_pop($labelarray), 0, -3));
  wp_enqueue_script($label + '-js', $file , array('jquery'), '1.0.0');
}
```